# How to represent the square root of a density matrix via the Glauber-Sudarshan representation?

Tags: quantum-optics, density-operator, coherent-states

I am trying to calculate the quantum Fisher Information of some quantum states which are represented via their P (Glauber-Sudarshan) representation,

$$\rho = \int P_\rho(\alpha) |{\alpha}\rangle \langle\alpha| d^2 \alpha,$$

where $|{\alpha} \rangle$ are coherent states. In order to do that, one option involves calculating fidelities of these states, which in turn need the evaluation of their square roots. Is there a simple way to express the P representation $P_{\sqrt{\rho}}(\alpha)$ of the square root of an operator $\rho$ as a function of the operator's own P representation $P_\rho(\alpha)$?

Comment: Compute P-function of $\rho^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and analytically continue? This will be easy for Gaussian states and supposedly difficult for non Gaussian sates.